# Wie verbreitet ist „Schlot“ als Synonym zu „Schlingel“?

Tags: meaning, synonym, colloquial

Wenn meine Mutter – mit westfälischen und ostniedersächsischen Einflüssen – früher mit mir oder meinen Geschwistern geschimpft hat, aber eigentlich nicht richtig sauer war, nannte sie uns statt *Schlingel* oder *Frechdachs* häufig *Schlot*. (*Lausbub* wäre wohl ebenfalls synonym, aber süddeutsch, und ich weiß nicht, ob wirklich irgendwer *Lausejunge* sagt.) Der passende Ausruf wäre:

> Du (kleiner) Schlot, du!

Ich habe den Begriff, der natürlich auch sowas wie ‚Schornstein‘ (bei Fabriken und Vulkanen) heißt, mal in verschiedenen ein- und zweisprachigen Online-Wörterbüchern nachgeschlagen. Manche führten gar keine Anwendbarkeit auf Menschen auf ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schlot), [Free Dictionary](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/schlot), [Open Thesaurus](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/Schlot), [Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-bin/wort_www.exe?site=1&Wort=schlot), [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende/?lang=de&searchLoc=1&search=schlot), [Dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=schlot)). [Pons](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?l=deen&in=de&q=schlot) nennt immerhin ‚Nichtsnutz‘, [DWDS](http://dwds.de/?qu=Schlot) und [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schlot) haben ähnliche Definitionen:

> (salopp, abwertend) **baumlanger**, nichtsnutziger, ungehobelter Kerl
>
> (salopp, abwertend) **hochgewachsener**, ungeschliffener, nichtsnutziger Mensch

Meine Hervorhebungen zeigen, dass die Körpergröße nach Ansicht der Wörterbücher offenbar essentiell ist. Sie würde helfen, die Wortherkunft mit den entsprechenden Schornsteinen zu erklären. Das passt aber nicht mit meiner Erfahrung zusammen, in der das Wort (nur) für Kinder verwendet wurde.

Lässt sich die mir bekannte Bedeutung anderweitig belegen oder handelt es sich womöglich um eine eigentümliche Abwandlung, die nicht weit genug über meine Familie hinausreicht, um messbar zu sein?

Comment: Aus Ba-Wü kenne ich Lausbua (Lausbub), ein Hallodri oder ein Bengel.  Schlot habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: In Bayern das gleiche; Schlot ist hier ohnehin eher ungebräuchlich zugunsten von Kamin, siehe [hier](https://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_3/f14c/)

Comment: In süd-Nds ist es auch in dem von dir beschriebenen Zusammenhang "Du kleiner Schlot" gebräuchlich. Aber auch "rauchen wie ein Schlot" habe ich gehört

Comment: @Medi1Saif Das nehme ich als anekdotisches Indiz dafür, dass es keine Eigenart meiner Mutter ist.

Comment: *rauchen wie ein Schlot*,  ja, *du Schlot*, nein. Nie gehört, nie benutzt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fazit**: 
Das Wort wird für lange Schlackse wie auch für verschiedene Varianten von Nichtsnutzen benutzt, ohne dass sich daraus eine Identität ergibt.

**Details:**
Eine Auswertung mit dem [Trierer Wörterbuchnetz](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/startGlobalSearch.tcl?stichwort=Schlot), die oft empfehlenswert ist bei veralteten und regional beschränkten Begriffen ergibt:

[Grimmsches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS12199#XGS12199):

> schlot, auf personen bezogen und einen ungeschliffenen menschen
>   bezeichnend, scheint erst in der neueren studentensprache üblich
>   geworden zu sein. der schloten in diesem sinne Albrecht 202b. [Bd. 15,
>   Sp. 783]

[Pfälzisches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=PfWB&lemid=PS03485):

> 4. 'nichtsnutziger Kerl', auch Schimpfw. [ ￼ HB-Höch]; vgl. PfWB Schlotte 6 c. — Südhess. V 462/63; RhWB Rhein. VII 1376.

[Rheinisches Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?lemid=PS03485&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&bookref=7,1376,16&sigle=RhWB):

> ￼  PfWB PfWB ElsWB Schlot VII das Wort ist aus dem Nhd., bes. in den Städten verbr., nicht rein mdl., u. zwar -ō-, –ō:-, Pl. -tə(n) m.:
>
> - 1. Fabrikschornstein. —
> - 2. übertr.
>
>      - a. verächtl. sachl. Mund Kobl-Güls. —
>      - b. persönl.
>      - α. lange Schl. hochaufgeschossener, hagerer Mensch MGladb. —
>      - β. Tagedieb Kreuzn-Pferdsf, Ottw-Eppelborn. —
>      - γ. ungehobelter Mensch Rip, Nfrk, bes. in der Studentenspr.
>
> schlotig -ō:t- Altk-Birken Adj.: nicht fest geschlossen, vom Kohlkopf.

Das Entziffern mancher Einträge dauert so lange, dass man seine Frage oft vergessen hat, bevor man richtig angefangen hat.

Wegen der Schwierigkeit die Formatierung hier rüberzuretten bitte auch die Links konsultieren. Das ist auch nicht viel lesbarer, aber anders. ;)

Schließlich das [Südhessesische Wörterbuch](http://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/rsrec/sn/shwb/entry/Schlot), welches nur als Bild vorliegt, rechte Spalte, ab Mitte: Schlot ... 3. "unordentlicher, schlampiger, liderlicher Mensch", "nachlässig, gleichgültiger", "energieloser, schlaffer, weichlicher ~", ... "Taugenichts, Tunichgut" ...

und so geht es dahin.

Answer (score 3):

Ich bin in Verden / Aller geboren. In meiner Verwandschaft (Niedersachsen / Ostpreußen) war das Wort in der Bedeutung von Schlawiner oder Schlingel gebräuchlich.

Mit der gleichen Bedeutung benutzt übrigens Klaus Hoffmann dieses Wort in seinem Lied *Adieu Emile*:

> weil Du ihr Hausfreund bist, Du Schlot...

Comment: Willkommen auf dem StackExchange der deutschen Sprache. Wenn Du magst, kannst Du Dir die [tour] anschauen, oder einen Blick ins [help] werfen. Viel Spaß!